# Reduce list items width to occupy exact size of text content in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I was looking for a way to remove white space that is usually created during the line break of link elements and came up with the `flex-basis: 0` solution which works fine for the major version of the browsers except for IE11.

Here is the example of the white space I've mentioned above:[image]

I will appreciate if somebody can suggest a similar possibility that will also support IE11

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
}

.menuItem {
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.menuItem a {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.menuItem a:after {
  content: '\25be';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) { 
  .noWhiteSpace .menuItem {
    flex-basis: 0;
  } 
}
```

```html
<ul class='menu'>
  <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some MoreText</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<h2>No White Space</h2>
<ul class='menu noWhiteSpace'>
  <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some MoreText</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Update with `flex-basis: auto:`**
The following approach indeed restores the width of the list items but brings back the issue of elements creating white space when breaking into two lines.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use  **flex-basis: auto;** for Internet Explorer.

> Reason is, **when a non-auto flex-basis is specified, Internet
>   Explorer 10 and 11 always uses a content-box box model to calculate
>   the size of a flex item.**

Reference:

[Browser compatibility for flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#Browser_compatibility)

modified code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.menu {
  display: flex;
}

.menuItem {
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.menuItem a {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.menuItem a:after {
  content: '\25be';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) { 
  .noWhiteSpace .menuItem {
    flex-basis: auto;
  } 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class='menu'>
  <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some MoreText</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<h2>No White Space</h2>
<ul class='menu noWhiteSpace'>
  <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some MoreText</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
    <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Some Text</a>
  </li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, Deepak. It indeed helps to restore the width, maybe you are aware of the possibility to shrink the elements in the IE so that they behave like `flex-basis: 0` in chrome. (I've updated the question with the screenshot of how `flex-basis: auto` looks in the IE11 in certain viewport width :-)

Comment: I check the issue with Chrome and IE and both shows the empty space. which increase or decrease while resizing the window. you can add more css media classes for different widths and try to set the different values for padding-right may help to avoid this extra space or simply add the down arrow with the text inside tags may help to remove the space.